# How to distribute a jar program without requiring clients to download JDK?

Tags: java, jar, exe, distribute

Can there be some converters or packer that would make my program run on windows? Maybe downloading JRE in the background or smt like this, so clients are not required to go to their site and download it manually

I tried some programs like j2e and some online converters, but they aren't precise (my program appears differently)

Comment: Have you tried/considered creating a self-contained application (i.e., embed the JRE), such as via [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/packaging-overview.html)?

Comment: This question has been asked many times before in various ways.  Please read the duplinks.  If they don't help, Google can find lots more Q&A's, articles, etc on this.